# How can I use breakpoints inside createMuiTheme? Material UI & React.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Maybe not the right approach but I want to create some 'global' styles for headings for example. Something like this:

```
const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
    headings: {
        h1: {
            fontSize: 28,
            // Obviously this does not work...
            [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
                fontSize: 24
            },
        },
        h2: {
            fontSize: 24,
        }
    }
}
```

then I can use them in my components like this:

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
    myElement: {
        ...theme.headings.h1,
        // ... other styles
    }
}
```

This does work but the issue I face is I want the headings to be responsive and respect Material UI's breakpoints, but I can't use them inside the createMuiTheme itself? What is the way to do this correctly so I can just spread in my styles that INCLUDE the responsive styles all in one?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `createBreakpoints` method

Example:

```
// theme.js

import createBreakpoints from '@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints'
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const breakpoints = createBreakpoints({})

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        [breakpoints.up('md')]: {
          minWidth: '200px',
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})

export default theme
```

*(tested: material-ui 4.0.1)*

Comment: yeah, I decided to just create another dummy blank theme and then just use that theme inside my main theme. The same type of thing.

Comment: createBreakpoints is considered private https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-1 "Be aware that we only support first and second level imports. Anything deeper is considered private and can cause issues, such as module duplication in your bundle."

Comment: Does anyone try this createBreakpoints function with Material version 5? Is it the same?

Comment: It's removed in v5, because it was private so not really exposed. I am still looking for an alternative though

Comment: Hi @EricBurel I think it's still there..  check out in the git, `material-ui/packages/mui-system/src/createTheme/createBreakpoints.js`, but now, in the v5, is in a different folder.. and as is a new version, I don't know if it's the best solution. I haven't worked with the new version yet

Comment: Perfect,  much thanks @RicardoCanelas, see my updated answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69175058/5513532

Comment: However creating an intermediate theme seems to be the preferred solution.

Comment: Great answer, tested and working in ver "5.4.0"

Answer (score 16):

**V5 update**

Preferred solution is to create an intermediate theme ([source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/28330#issuecomment-919852856)):

```js
let theme = createTheme()
theme = createTheme(theme , { 
  h5: {
          fontSize: "1.5", //24px
          fontWeight: title.fontWeight,
          fontFamily: sansSerif(title.fontFamily),
          letterSpacing: title.letterSpacing,
          lineHeight: "2.1rem", //34px
          color: "#636e72",
          [theme.breakpoints.between("xs", "sm")]: {
            fontSize: "1.25rem", // 20px
            lineHeight: "1.9rem", //  30px
          },
          [theme.breakpoints.between("sm", "md")]: {
            fontSize: "1.4rem", //24px
            lineHeight: "2rem", // 35px
          },
        },
})
```

If you used `createBreakpoints`: as pointed out by @Ricardo Canelas comment, `createBreakpoints` has simply moved, right import is now: `import createBreakpoints from "@mui/system/createTheme/createBreakpoints"`. However, keep in mind that this is still a private API at the time of writing so can move/break at any version update.
Preferred solution is to use an intermediate theme.

Answer (score 6):

From https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18017#issuecomment-545914925

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const theme = createMuiTheme();

theme.overrides = {
  MuiTypography: {
    hero: {
      [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]:{
        fontSize: '11rem',
        background: 'red',
      },
      fontSize: '3.75rem',
      lineHeight: '5rem',
      fontWeight: 700,
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a side note, but if you want to change the values of the breakpoints you can edit the `breakpoints` object created with `createBreakpoints({})`:

```
import createBreakpoints from '@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints'

const breakpoints = createBreakpoints({})
// outputs {xs: 0, sm: 600, md: 960, lg: 1280, xl: 1920}

breakpoints.values.lg = 1024
// outputs {xs: 0, sm: 600, md: 960, lg: 1024, xl: 1920}
```

You could also add additional breakpoints in a similar way if you didn't want to edit the existing items:

```
breakpoints.values['xxl'] = 3000
// outputs {xs: 0, sm: 600, md: 960, lg: 1280, xl: 1920, xxl: 3000}
```

In my project the breakpoints that Material-UI has set (xs: 0, sm: 600, etc.) didn't line up with the ones I was using already in my project, so I had to change them.

Comment:  Good explanation... That's why I imported the createBreakpoints method.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use something like this -

```
MuiInputBase: {
  defaultProps: {
    sx: {
      fontSize: {
        xs: '16px',
        md: '14px',
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const theme = createMuiTheme();

theme.typography.h3 = {
  fontSize: '1.2rem',
  '@media (min-width:600px)': {
    fontSize: '1.5rem',
  },
  [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
    fontSize: '2.4rem',
  },
};
```

https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes